# Button click in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a website that is being launched in the default web browser on the user's system that navigates to a specific web page that the user request. How would I then be able to have the UWP click on buttons once that webpage loads. I'm assuming based on my research it will be through the use of `HttpClient`, but I'm not trying to reload the page and I'm unsure on how to integrate `LaunchUriAsync` with `HttpClient`. This is what I have so far

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(url));
            var httpClint = new HttpClient();
            var elements = await httpClint.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url));
            var htmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadXml(elements);
```

Comment: Loading the raw HTML would be useful if you intend to write a web browser. But I doubt that's what you're trying to do. Easier would be to load the page in to a WebView control and then inject script into the WebView to maniuplate the page.

Comment: @RaymondChen what do you mean by webview

Comment: [WebView sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlWebView) shows how to use WebView to load a web page. But it looks like you cannot inject script into that WebView. You can do it with [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/).

Comment: @RaymondChen from the research it doesn't appear that WebView2 would work for an UWP  application.